# What are other words worth learning that follow this pattern with 象?

Tags: characters, word-requests, character-components

Today I realised that:

象 means "elephant" which is the biggest land-dwelling animal,

亻+ 象 = 像 means "statue" which is the biggest person (I mean, a statue is the biggest representation of a human in the world),

木 + 象 = 橡 means "oak" which is the biggest tree.

Are there more of this 象 pattern? I'm sure these are not a coincidence.

Comment: 豫，yu，予➕象，in ancient China，it means happy ，its a very very old word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character 象 is a pictograph that depicts the image of an elephant. Its role in 像 and 橡 is as a phonetic component. It doesn't indicate  'size' or 'largest'.

像 (like; resemblance) and 橡(oak) have nothing to do with elephants. (象 means elephant is irrelevant, it is there for the sound)

*Side note: 雕像 (statue) can be any size, some can be held in your hand*